# spark scala - how to calculate the md5 of multiple column based on the list of columns

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have list which contains the names of column. I need to concat this columns and then create and `md5` and append to the dataframe.

**example**

I have table with `fname`, `lname`, `address`. my resulting dataframe should look like. `fname`, `lname`, `address` and `md5(concat_ws(",",fname, lname))`

my list would contains `fname` and `lname`.

**code**

```scala
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window
val businessCols = List("fname", "lname")
val df = spark.table(s"{databaseName}.${databaseName}")
val new_df = df.
                withColumn("concatenated_cols",concat_ws(",",$"businessCols": _*)).
                withColumn("md5_hash", md5($"concatenated_cols"))
```

[image]

**Error**

```
found   : org.apache.spark.sql.ColumnName
 required: Seq[org.apache.spark.sql.Column]
                withColumn("concatenated_cols",concat_ws(",",$"businessCols": _*)).
```

Comment: find? what do you mean?

Comment: I mean calculate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix this by creating a new list

```scala
import org.apache.spark.sql.Column
val cols = businessCols.foldLeft(List[Column]()){(acc,l) => acc ++ List(col(l))}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.security.MessageDigest
import spark.implicits._
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.concat_ws

case class Test(fname: String, lname: String, address: String)

def md5(s: String): Array[Byte] = {
  MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5").digest(s.getBytes)
}
val df1 = spark.createDataset(Seq(Test("1", "1", "2")))
df1.withColumn("md5(concat_ws(\",\",fname, lname))", lit(md5(concat_ws(",", $"fname", $"lname")
  .toString()))).show(false)
```

Comment: thanks for the code. However the what I want to achive is this. column names are dynmic and not static. it's coming from the list

Comment: @GaurangShah what does your list look like?